# Can a 1-side, 1-border object exist in 3D?

Tags: 3d, geometry

We are three friends discussing whether a three dimensional object with a single side and a single are can possibly exist.

1. I first came up with a Moebius strip as an affirmative example
2. The second friend came up with a Klein bottle with a hole / drill (in order to provide the border)
3. The third and last friend argues that neither the strip or the bottle are valid examples because a Klein´s bottle is really a projection of a R4 object in R3, and because, in any case, both objects must have thickness in order to exist, so the strip would actually have two borders instead of just one.

Can a 1-side, 1-border object exist in 3D? Or is the third friend right with his "must have thickness in R3 in order to <> (be fisically feasible)"

Many Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between "existing in 3d" and "existing in our physical universe".  In our mathematical definition of $\mathbb{R}^3$, yes these objects can and do exist, but once you move to our physical universe where "objects" must consist of matter, and matter is made of molecules, and molecules have nonzero thickness, there is no longer any physical object with zero thickness.

Comment: We should agree some degree of "solid idealization" for the original question. Maybe that's the key to satisfy the third friend. I guess there is no point in defining a "border" at molecular level. Thanks for the thought :-)

Comment: An interesting thought perhaps, in a similar manner there is no physical *object* larger than an atom which is a pure sphere in our universe.  At best it will be a polyhedron with an absurdly high number of sides, again due to the discrete nature of atoms and molecules.  Your third friend may enjoy that tidbit.  It doesn't make circles and spheres any less useful, just that we need to be satisfied with a certain level of accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Moebius strip is an obvious affirmative example, it has one border and one side. It proves that the answer to your question is yes.

The Klein bottle with a hole *is* a moebius strip. And your third friend is entirely wrong, a klein bottle with a hole *can* be embedded into $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!
Also, thanks for pointing out that a Klein bottle is nothing but a stretched Moebius strip, I hadn't realized that. +1 as soon as I register this account.